# decryption using hill cipher technique

Tags: encryption, matrix

In hill cipher we use a key matrix to encrypt a plain text.the same way we find inverse of the key matrix to decrypt the cipher text.finding the inverse of the key matrix in the decryption side makes the decryption process a bit complex.so is there any way to decrypt the cipher text with the same key matrix without finding the inverse of the key matrix in the decryption side?

Comment: I don't think you can, otherwise the encryption would have been easier to "reverse", matrix reversal is a computational issue, this is why it was chosen as the method to protect the key

Answer (score 1):

You can, but then you need to solve a system of linear equations for each text block. Since this is almost as expensive as inverting the matrix, it is not a useful approach.